# Flag for mod, locking, etc. for tag wikis

Tags: feature-request, flags, tag-wiki

In case of [edit wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_war) (hopefully soon to be [visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57997/tag-wiki-visible-edit-history-rollback)) or other problems like inappropriate content in a tag wiki I can't edit, we need the ability to flag tag-wikis for moderator attention.

Moderators should probably be able to lock those like normal posts if that isn't possible yet.

Comment: Locking would have to be temporary, otherwise it's not much of a wiki.

Comment: @Andy: I mean locking as in *"locked until the current problem is resolved"*.

Comment: Now that we have a backing post, I will look at adding a flag button

Comment: @waffles - did anything ever happen with this request?  I'd love to flag this wiki excerpt for attention, as it plagiarizes text, but I can't come up with a better way to clean up the text:  http://stackoverflow.com/tags/eq/info

Comment: nada ... you probably should bounty this

Answer (score 5):

Push it to the community eyeballing changes with a **[Recent Changes to Tag Wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/recent-edits)** page.

It's not enough that you [first have to find your way through the thicket](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58317/tag-wiki-a-better-way-to-find-it), but [tracking your changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59289/editing-a-tag-wiki-should-show-in-your-activity-log) with a smothering of sardines in a cat lady's home only gets you enough before you're downed by the whiskers.

Another thought to flag is a page noting recent changes to tag wikis. Like a stink smear, greasing up the recent activity oil when the mechanic pulls that dipstick out and wipes it down with that rag that's been all over town.

And then everybody can share in the blame (as well as pitchfork running) of [bad and poor-faith edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58002/how-professional-do-we-want-the-tag-wiki-pages).