# Please Allow Feedback on Tag Wikis

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-wiki, feedback

I was just using the [10k "Recent Tag Wikis"](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-wikis) tool to see what others have been up to, and I just noticed: there's nothing I can do about issues I've seen with the wikis.

I don't have access to edit most of the wikis I've seen issues with, so I can't just clean up the problems I've seen; I can't send email to the creators of the wikis; I can't flag them for moderator attention; and I can't comment on them.

Examples:

1. The [MSDTC](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/msdtc/info) wiki should include links to some basic information on working with transactions. It's not much use to someone who doesn't quite know what a transaction is, much less a distributed transaction. "[Transaction Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w97s6fw4.aspx)" might be a good link.
2. The [WSS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wss/info) wiki should mention that Sharepoint Server 2007 is frequently referred to as "Microsoft Office Sharepoint Server" or "MOSS".
3. The [WIF](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/wif/info) wiki might add a link to an article on  what federated security is about. It could even mention that the codeword for WIF was "Geneva".

I don't really like the idea that the only way to provide feedback like this is here on meta. I think we need something more direct, and perhaps directed at the wiki authors.

An alternative that I don't like would be to create a question here on meta that wiki authors would subscribe to in RSS. One would create a new question for each tag wiki. The base "RSS" question would be updated to include links to the separate per-wiki questions. Presumably, the wiki authors would see the feed and see that there were issues with their wikis.

That sounds too formal, too complicated. Let's provide feedback mechanisms right on the wiki pages.

Comment: This appears to be implemented on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completed, anyone can submit edits for tag wikis there is a related open request for [Flag for mod, locking, etc. for tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58310/flag-for-mod-locking-etc-for-tag-wikis) .