# Would it be a good idea to have unified format for tag wiki pages?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki

It is still a very new feature, but I think it is already visible that tag wiki pages could turn out a bit messy - anything about everything in all forms.

Do you think readers would benefit if all tag wikis dedicated to some specific technology (not generic tags like "security", "algorithm") had one unified document structure (maybe even with all fields required), like:

- Explanation what kind of questions should or shouldn't be tagged with this tag.
- General info about this topic and links to official site.
- Links to official documentation and faq
- List of common problems and tasks and guidelines for their solution (SO questions or external links to tutorials and docs)
- Links to most valuable questions on SO
- List of subprojects and closely related technologies
- Competitor technologies

(that's something I came up with in 5 min for example sake, would need to be much more thought through).

Comment: Some of the discussion [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58002/how-professional-do-we-want-the-tag-wiki-pages) and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59415/are-there-any-resources-for-writing-a-tag-wiki) relates to this. In particular, I side with [Shog9 here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58002/are-rolling-heads-a-fire-hazard/58280#58280) about the downsides with making a fixed/required format.